# Pass files from Amazon S3 through NodeJS server without exposing S3 URL?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I am trying to integrate S3 file storage into my NodeJS application. [This tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node) explaining how to upload *directly* to S3 is very good, but it's not suitable for my needs, as I want the files to only be accessible via my web app's API. I don't want the files to be publicly available at their S3 URLs, I just want them to be available through for example `/api/files/<user_id>/<item_id>/<filename>`.

The reason I want **downloads** to go through my API is so that I can check that the user is permitted to view this particular file.

The reason I want **uploads** to go through my server is so that I know which `<item_id>` to assign the filename, as this will be the same as its MongoDB `_id` property. I can't do this if I upload the file to S3 before the item has a Mongo `_id` in the first place.

I've looked but couldn't find a straightforward tutorial for how to stream files from S3 to the client and vice versa through my NodeJS application.

Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A combination of an express middleware (to check the authorization of the user making the request) and the use of the [Node AWS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) should do the trick.

Here is a full example using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) for the upload.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({
  dest: "tmp/"
});
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Configure AWS SDK here
var s3 = new AWS.s3({
  params: {
    Bucket: 'xxx'
  }
});

/**
 * Authentication middleware
 *
 * It will be called for any routes starting with /files
 */
app.use("/files", function (req, res, next) {
  var authorized = true; // use custom logic here
  if (!authorized) {
    return res.status(403).end("not authorized");
  }
  next();
});

// Route for the upload
app.post("/files/upload", upload.single("form-field-name"), function (req, res) {
  var fileInfo = console.log(req.file);
  var fileStream = fs.readFileSync(fileInfo.path);
  var options = {
    Bucket: 'xxx',
    Key: 'yyy/'+fileName,
    Body: fileStream
  };

  s3.upload(options, function (err) {
    // Remove the temporary file
    fs.removeFileSync("tmp/"+fileInfo.path); // ideally use the async version
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).end("Upload to s3 failed");
    }
    res.status(200).end("File uploaded");
  });
});

// Route for the download
app.get("/files/download/:name", function (req, res) {
  var fileName = req.params.name;
  if (!fileName) {
    return res.status(400).end("missing file name");
  }
  var options = {
    Bucket: 'xxx',
    Key: 'yyy/'+fileName
  };
  res.attachment(fileName);
  s3.getObject(options).createReadStream().pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Obviously this is only partially tested and lacks of proper error handling - but it hopefully it should give you a rough idea of how to implement it.

Comment: Thank you for this! I decided to start this using the s3 library which provides some simple helper functions for uploading and downloading, but I will use this answer for reference on other things.

Comment: Are you referring to [node-s3-client](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client)? If yes I must warn you, I've had very bad experiences with it. See for instance [issue#127](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client/issues/127), [issue#121](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client/issues/121)

Comment: Oh. Yes it is that one. Hmmm :/ Ok I will stick with this for the prototype phase but will do it your way for phase 2.

Comment: Yep, in my opinion you should not use node-s3. I've spent countless hours trying to debug weird bugs that I tought were caused by my code, but were actually due to the library... As the author clearly says [here](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client/issues/129#issuecomment-214487914), this library isn't officially supported anymore. You may want to take a look at [knox](https://github.com/Automattic/knox) and [intimidate](https://github.com/jergason/intimidate) (a fork of knox, which adds the ability to retry failed requests)

Comment: I briefly looked at knox, but the reason I went with node-s3-client is because that seems like the only library offering high level uploads and downloads. I'm not yet comfortable dealing with low level stuff like streams... in which case do you have any other library recommendations?

Comment: Not really, but some might exist. In any case if you start to experience strange issues (such as files not uploading randomly), keep in mind there are high chances it comes from node-s3. Good luck!

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your advice! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [S3 REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html). It will allows you to make signed request to GET or PUT your bucket's objects directly from your backend.

The principle is similar from the one described in your link. 
Your backend need to use the [AWS JS SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) to create a signed URL to manipulate an object. You are free to do any check you want prior or after requesting something from S3 in your Express routes.

Here is a simple GET example (it is not fully functional, just the main idea):

```
...
[assume that you are in an express route with req/res objects]
...
var aws = require('aws-sdk'),
  s3 = new aws.S3();

aws.config.region = 'your_region';
aws.config.credentials = {
  accessKeyId: 'your_key',
  secretAccessKey: 'your_secret'
};

s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {Bucket: 'your_bucket', Key: 'your_file_name', Expires: 3600}, function (error, url) {
  if (error || !url) {
    //error while creating the URL
    res.status(500).end();
  } else {
    //make a request to the signed URL to get the file and pipe the res to the client
    request({
      url: url
    }).pipe(res);
  }
});
```

You will [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html#Amazon_S3__Getting_a_pre-signed_URL_for_a_getObject_operation__getSignedUrl_) find more examples from Amazon.