# Piping a file straight to the client using Node.js and Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, express, download, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

So I want to pipe a file straight to the client; how I am currently doing it is create a file to disk, then sending that file straight to the client.

```
router.get("/download/:name", async (req, res) => {

  const s3 = new aws.S3();
  const dir = "uploads/" + req.params.name + ".apkg"
  let file = fs.createWriteStream(dir);

  await s3.getObject({
    Bucket: <bucket-name>,
    Key: req.params.name + ".apkg"
  }).createReadStream().pipe(file);

  await res.download(dir);
});
```

I just looked up that `res.download()` only serves locally. Is there a way you can do it directly from AWS S3 to Client download? i.e. pipe files straight to user. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

As described in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431757/pass-files-from-amazon-s3-through-nodejs-server-without-exposing-s3-url):
You can simply pipe the read stream into the response instead of the piping it to the file, just make sure to supply the correct `Content-Type` and to set it as an attachment, so the browser will know how to handle the response properly.

```
res.attachment(req.params.name);
await s3.getObject({
    Bucket: <bucket-name>,
    Key: req.params.name + ".apkg"
}).createReadStream().pipe(res);
```

On more pattern for this is to create a signed url directly to the S3 object and then let the client download straight from S3, instead of streaming it from your node webserver. This will reduce the workload from your web server.

You will need to use the [getSignedUrl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) method from the AWS S3 SDK for JS.
Then, Once you have the URL, just return it to your client to download the file by themselves.

You should take into account that once you give the client a signed URL that has download permissions for, say, 5 minutes, they will only be able to download that file during those next 5 minutes. And you should also take into account that they will be able to pass that URL to anyone else for download during those 5 minutes, so it is dependant on how secure you need this to be.

Answer (score 0):

S3 can be used to content so I would do the following.

1. Add CORS headers on your node response. This will enable browser to download from another origin i.e. S3.
2. Enable S3 web server on your bucket.
3. Script to download redirect from S3 - this you could achieve in JS.

Use signed URL as suggested in the other post if you need to protect S3 content.